# How can you get the garbage collection policies for Google Cloud Bigtable?

Tags: garbage-collection, google-cloud-bigtable

The docs for [garbage collection](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/garbage-collection) explain how to set the garbage collection policies with cbt but don't explain how to read the policies. The [cbt reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference) doesn't seem to have any command to get garbage collection either. As far as I can tell, this isn't available in the GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [page](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/configuring-garbage-collection) about configuring garbage collection. It provides examples of how to set and update garbage-collection policies when you use Cloud Bigtable client libraries or the cbt command-line tool.

The answer to your question is that you can view garbage collection policies of certain tables by running this cbt command:

```
cbt ls TABLE_ID
```

Here's [another reference](https://cgrant.io/cloud/gcp/data/getting-started-with-bigtable/#garbage-collection) written by other devs showing the sample output of the command.